# Alexa Skill: is it possible to have Alexa play a .mp3 from Alexa Developer Console - Alexa Hosted?

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I'm trying to create a skill for Alexa that reproduces .mp3 files based on the category of the tg I choose.
I state that I never used `node.js` and that I looked at a course on how to create alexa skill.
Until now I have created the skeleton of the skill and I have created a `database.json` file that contains the various categories of news with attached links.

**INDEX.JS**

```
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');
const database = require('./database'); 

function getCategoryStreamUrl(name) { 
    let category = database.find(e => e.name === name);
    if (category !== null && category !== undefined) {
        return category.StreamUrl;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

function getCategoryUpdateDate(name) { 
    let category = database.find(e => e.name === name);
    if (category !== null && category !== undefined) {
        return category.UpdateDate;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

const LaunchRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'LaunchRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speakOutput = 'Welcome, with this skill you can listen to our TG. You can choose a category or say Help.';
        const repromptOutput = 'You can choose a category or say Help. What do you want to do?'
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(repromptOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
const ScegliCategoriaIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'ScegliCategoriaIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speakOutput = 'The TGs available are: Political, Lazio, Environment, Health, School, Pediatrics, Rehabilitation, Agriculture, Psychology and Youth. Which do you want to hear?'
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(repromptOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
 const CategoriaIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'CategoriaIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const filledSlots = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots;
        const slotValues = getSlotValues(filledSlots);

        console.log("CategoriaIntentHandler >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
        console.log(slotValues);

        const categoryName = slotValues["category"].synonym
        const categoryStreamUrl = getCategoryStreamUrl(categoryName);
        const categoryUpdateDate = getCategoryUpdateDate(categoryName);

        var speakOutput = "";
        if (categoryStreamUrl !== "") {
            speakOutput = "You have chosen the TG " + categoryName + ". The TG was updated on " + categoryUpdateDate + ". " + categoryStreamUrl + ". If you want to hear other news, name another TG or you can say STOP to close this skill.";
        } else {
            speakOutput = "I'm sorry, the selected TG is not available. You can say the name of another TG or 'categories' to hear the list of available categories. What do you want to do?";
        }

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt("If you want to hear more news, say the name of another TG. You can say 'categories' to listen to the list of available categories or you can say STOP to close this skill. What do you want to do?")
            .getResponse();
    }
};
const HelpIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AMAZON.HelpIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speakOutput = "You can say 'categories' to listen to the list of available categories or you can say STOP to close this skill. What do you want to do?";
        const repromptOutput = "If you want to stop listening, say STOP."

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(repromptOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
const CancelAndStopIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && (Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AMAZON.CancelIntent'
                || Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AMAZON.StopIntent');
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speakOutput = "Goodbye!";
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
const SessionEndedRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'SessionEndedRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        // Any cleanup logic goes here.
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder.getResponse();
    }
};

// The intent reflector is used for interaction model testing and debugging.
// It will simply repeat the intent the user said. You can create custom handlers
// for your intents by defining them above, then also adding them to the request
// handler chain below.
const IntentReflectorHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const intentName = Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope);
        const speakOutput = `You just triggered ${intentName}`;

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
            .getResponse();
    }
};

// Generic error handling to capture any syntax or routing errors. If you receive an error
// stating the request handler chain is not found, you have not implemented a handler for
// the intent being invoked or included it in the skill builder below.
const ErrorHandler = {
    canHandle() {
        return true;
    },
    handle(handlerInput, error) {
        console.log(`~~~~ Error handled: ${error.stack}`);
        const speakOutput = `I'm sorry I did not understand. Say 'Help' to know the available commands.`;

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};

function getSlotValues (filledSlots) {

    let slotValues = {}; //

    console.log('The filled slots: ' + JSON.stringify(filledSlots));
    Object.keys(filledSlots).forEach(function(item) {

    var name = filledSlots[item].name;

    if(filledSlots[item]&&
        filledSlots[item].resolutions &&
        filledSlots[item].resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority[0] &&
        filledSlots[item].resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority[0].status &&
        filledSlots[item].resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority[0].status.code ) {

        switch (filledSlots[item].resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority[0].status.code) {
            case "ER_SUCCESS_MATCH": 
                slotValues[name] = {
                    "synonym": filledSlots[item].value,
                    "resolved": filledSlots[item].resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority[0].values[0].value.name,
                    "isValidated": true
                };
                break;
            case "ER_SUCCESS_NO_MATCH": 
                slotValues[name] = {
                    "synonym": filledSlots[item].value,
                    "resolved": filledSlots[item].value,
                    "isValidated":false
                };
                break;
            }
        } else { 
            slotValues[name] = {
                "synonym": filledSlots[item].value,
                "resolved": filledSlots[item].value,
                "isValidated": false
            };
        }
    },this);
    return slotValues;
}

// The SkillBuilder acts as the entry point for your skill, routing all request and response
// payloads to the handlers above. Make sure any new handlers or interceptors you've
// defined are included below. The order matters - they're processed top to bottom.
exports.handler = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom()
    .addRequestHandlers(
        LaunchRequestHandler,
        ScegliCategoriaIntentHandler,
        CategoriaIntentHandler,
        HelpIntentHandler,
        CancelAndStopIntentHandler,
        SessionEndedRequestHandler,
        IntentReflectorHandler, // make sure IntentReflectorHandler is last so it doesn't override your custom intent handlers
    )
    .addErrorHandlers(
        ErrorHandler,
    )
    .lambda();
```

**DATABASE.JSON**

```
[
    {
        "uid":"ID",
        "updateDate": "DATA",
        "name": "NAME SLOT",
        "titleText": "TG 01",
        "mainText":"",
        "streamUrl":"https://www.mysite.it/tg.mp3",
        "redirectionUrl":"https://www.mysite.it/category/tg"
          },
    {
        etc_01
        },
{
        etc_02
        },
{
        etc_03
        },
]
```

The problem is that now it doesn't work, in fact when I ask alexa to tell me the *TG 01* she tells me:

> "You have chosen the TG 01. The TG was updated on undefinied. Undefinied. another TG or you can say STOP to close this skill. "

In short, it does not recognize `categoryUpdateDate` or `categoryStreamUrl`.

What do I have to do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the wrong data in both functions:

they should be: `category.updateDate` and `category.streamUrl`, because you are reading a JSON file. (maybe read [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) to understand better how to read and access JSON properties and so on..)

```
function getCategoryStreamUrl(name) { 
    let category = database.find(e => e.name === name);
    if (category !== null && category !== undefined) {
        return category.streamUrl;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

function getCategoryUpdateDate(name) { 
    let category = database.find(e => e.name === name);
    if (category !== null && category !== undefined) {
        return category.updateDate;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```